# Showing a Letter and Using it for a Mathematical Operation In Blackjack

Tags: python, variables, control-flow

I am working on a Blackjack project.

I want to be able to use the letter "A" in a list of integers 2-10.

I am getting lost in the passing of the value of a string, in this case 'A' into the sum() function for the cards then returning that value but showing the 'A' in the cards is where I am getting lost.

For instance:
cards = ['A',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

The list will randomly return 2 values ranging from A-10
Then if A is returned with another number I want to calculate the value of the letter A + the integer

It would print to the user something like
"Your hand is: [A,7] Total = 18"

This is what I have been experimenting with so far.

```
import random

A = ord("A") - 64
def deal():
  cards = [A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
  player = []
  dealer = []

  while len(player) < 2:
    player.append(random.choice(cards))
    dealer.append(random.choice(cards))

  return player, dealer

#this is ITERABLE UNPACK it separates the returned values from the deal() function and assigns them to their respective variables.

player, dealer = deal()

#sum the value of the cards

player_cards = sum(player)
dealer_cards = sum(dealer)

print(f"Your cards are {player}. Total  = {player_cards}")
print(f"The dealer shows [{dealer[0]}, *]. Total = {dealer_cards}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with cards, I would rather prefer to use `random.sample(cards, len(cards))` because this function emulates mixing of the cards.

```
# let's define cards
card_values = {'A': 11, 'K': 10, 'Q': 10, 'J': 10}
card_values.update({k: k for k in range(2, 11)}) 
# because I am too lazy to write all card values by hand
cards = card_values.keys()


def random_select(cards, k=2):
    """Select randomly k cards from cards.
    Return also the not-selected cards."""
    new_order = random.sample(cards, len(cards))
    return new_order[:k], new_order[k:]

# and you can choose first 2 by:
two_cards, rest_deck = random_select(cards, k=2)
# by altering k you can make the function select k cards.

# and for next player you do:
two_next_cards, rest_deck = random_select(rest_deck, k=2)

# in this way, the already selected cards are removed from the original deck (rest_deck).



def card_sums(cards, card2value=card_values):
    return sum([card2value[c] for c in cards])



def deal(players, cards, k=2):
    result = {}
    rest_cards = cards
    for player in players:
        chosen, rest_cards = random_select(rest_cards, k = k)
        result[player] = chosen
    return result, rest_cards
# players can be a dictionary
# or just a list of the players (strings).

players = {'player': [], 'dealer': []}
selected_cards, rest_cards = deal(players, cards, k=2)

print(f"Your cards are {selected_cards['player']}. Total  = {card_sums(selected_cards['player'])}")
print(f"The dealer shows {selected_cards['dealer']}. Total = {card_sums(selected_cards['dealer'])}")
```

Comment: This is very cool, thank you, but I can't get it to run, and it is confusing because it's really advanced. 

I can't recall what method this syntax is.

 new_order[:k], new_order[k:]

Comment: So now it works - sorry - I didn't tested it. there was 'cards' variable missing - which is just all possible cards - the keys fo the card_values dictionary.

Comment: `new_order[:k], new_order[k:]` is called list slicing in Python. it means select range of elements. `:k` means: from start to index `k` (exclusively) and `k:` from `k` (included) until end of list. by putting them next to each other in a return statement you actually create a tuple.

Comment: The previous answers don't exclude already selected cards - so they can be chosen again - which would be a bug.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! I am going through it with Thonny now to really try and wrap my head around this, and thank you for your explanation of list slicing. I have seen it in reference apps, and posts but never really applied. So appreciative!

Comment: Mr. Kim, I have been breaking up your code to try and really understand it. 
I started with the first section, which is incredibly clever. 

card_values = {'A': 11, 'K': 10, 'Q': 10, 'J': 10}
card_values.update({k: k for k in range(2, 11)}) 
# because I am too lazy to write all card values by hand
cards = card_values.keys()

Would it be correct to say that in card_values.update({k: k for k in range(2, 11)})

Comment: @BarryBrewer Great! I hope things are clear!

Comment: Sorry my comment timed out, yes, thank you!

Would it be correct to say that in card_values.update({k: k for k in range(2, 11)})

k is the for loop variable that holds the values that come from the range
(2,11) and since you put k on both sides of the colon that it gets updated as the same numbers? Amazing thinking.

Comment: @BarryBrewer - yes - by making entry into the dictionary with the pure numbers I can treat all cards uniformely and don't need to distinguish the different cases that it is a number card or abbreviated as letter.

Comment: @BarryBrewer - yes. `{k: k for k in range(2, 11)}` generates a dictionary by looping over `range(2, 11)` which is `[2, 3, .., 10]` (11 excluded like always in python ranges - because it is a 0-based system). the `{... for ... in ...}` is called a list expression - in this case a list expression for dictionaries. List expressions are an equivalent of `map()` functions in FP. But instead of `map()`, it is more pythonic in Python to use list-expressions. List expressions are very handy for saving some typing when generating lists (or dictionaries).

Comment: @BarryBrewer - so this time, it is `k : k` because key and value are identical for number cards. this "lists" expression is the same like: `result = {}; for k in range(2, 11): result[k] = k`. But using the lilst expression this becomes a one-liner.

Comment: Wow. Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: After reading your final comment I looked more deeply into list comprehension. Super cool!

Comment: @BarryBrewer Ah yeah list-comprehensions. You can do them with [  for in ] -> normal lists or with { :   for   in   } then they become dictionaries and with (   for in ) then they are generators (use up much less memory at once).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def get_sum(cards):
    return sum(card if not card == 'A' else 11 for card in cards)

player = ['A', 7]
dealer = [8, 'A']

player_cards = get_sum(player)
dealer_cards = get_sum(dealer)

print(f"Your cards are {', '.join([', '.join(str(i) for i in player)])}. Total  = {player_cards}")
print(f"The dealer shows {dealer[0]}. Total = {dealer_cards}")
```

Output:

```
Your cards are A, 7. Total  = 18
The dealer shows 8. Total = 19
```

If you have King, Queen and Jack, you can use this version:

```
player = ['A', 'K']

def get_sum(cards):
    vals = {'A': 11, 'K': 10, 'Q': 10, 'J': 10}
    return sum(vals.get(card, card) for card in cards)

print(get_sum(player))

print(f"Your cards are {player}. Total  = {player_cards}")
print(f"The dealer shows [{dealer[0]}, *]. Total = {dealer_cards}")
```

Output:

```
21
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am able to get the sum of card, but what I can't do is have this output example:

Example:
[A, 9] = 20

I think that you're onto something using the dictionary, so what I am looking for is to show either the Key (in the example an A) or the value (in the example the number 9)

Comment: Sorry my comment got timed out....

Thank you for your response. I may not understand it but I think I do.

I am able to get the sum of card, but what I can't do is have this output example:

Example:
[A, 9] = 20

I think that you're onto something using the dictionary, so what I am looking for is to show either the Key (in the example an A) or the value (in the example the number 9)

The A that is seen by the player needs to hold the value but be shown as the letter A.

Comment: I updated my solution. Is it what you expect?